# An issue about what's the type of a declaration which is surrounded by parentheses

Tags: c++, c++17, language-lawyer, declaration

In the section [dcl.meaning](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/dcl.meaning#6), it says:

> Thus, a declaration of a particular identifier has the form
> T D
> where **T is of the form attribute-specifier-seq <sub>opt</sub> decl-specifier-seq and D is a declarator**. Following is a recursive procedure for determining the type specified for the contained declarator-id by such a declaration.

> [bullet 6] In a declaration T D where D has the form
> ( D1 )
> the type of the contained declarator-id is the same as that of the contained declarator-id in the declaration
> T D1
> Parentheses do not alter the type of the embedded declarator-id, but they can alter the binding of  complex declarators.

However, consider the below code

```cpp
int main(){
  int* (ptr) = nullptr;
}
```

In my example, `(ptr)` conforms to the form `(D1)`, however it's not the **declarator**, the complete declarator in my example is `*ptr`. According to the bullet mentioned in the above, `(D1)` denotes `D`, `D` is the **declarator** of a declaration(note the emphasized part), that is, `(D1)` shall be the declarator of a declaration. Only the form `int (*ptr)` is the case of what bullet 6 is talking about.  The bullet 6 seems to does not cover the example  `int* (ptr)`. So, how to interpret such case? what's the type of such a declarator-id(`int* (ptr)`). If I misunderstand bullet 6, how to understand the bullet 6 correctly? Or Is the bullet 6 a defect of wording that ignore to cover such case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to continue to the next section. Bullet 6 is just one case, which does not apply here because your declaration is not of the form `T (D1)`. It is of the form `T D` with `T = int` and `D = *(ptr)`. `D = *D1` (matching here with `D1 = (ptr)`) is handled by [`[dcl.ptr]`](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/dcl.meaning#dcl.ptr-1):

> In a declaration `T D` where `D` has the form
>
> ```
> *attribute-specifier-seq_opt cv-qualifier-seq_opt D1
> ```
>
> and the type of the identifier in the declaration `T D1` is "`derived-declarator-type-list T`", then the type of the identifier of `D` is "*derived-declarator-type-list* *cv-qualifier-seq* pointer to `T`". The *cv-qualifiers* apply to the pointer and not to the object pointed to. Similarly, the optional *attribute-specifier-seq* appertains to the pointer and not to the object pointed to.

So, in order to know what `int *(ptr)` means, we consider first what `int (ptr)` means. *Now* your quote in `[dcl.meaning]` comes into play, saying that this is the same as `int ptr`. So, `int (ptr)` would declare the identifier `ptr` as type `int`. Then, by the rule I've quoted, `int *(ptr)` declares `ptr` as pointer to `int`.

Comment: yes,  you are right. The [dcl.meaning] does not intent to cover `int *(ptr)`. In other words, `(D1)` must be the complete declarator, which is the case  covered by [dcl.meaning]

Comment: Another question. why the sentence is not `where D is the form (D1)`? In my understanding, `where D has the form (D1)` means that `*(ptr)` is also the situation what the sentence talking about. Taken `(ptr)` as `(D1)` , taken `*(ptr)` as `D`, where D comprises the `(D1)`.

Comment: That's just not what those words mean. `*(ptr)` does not have form (does not match the pattern) `(D1)`. Period. `*(ptr)` has a syntactic subterm that has that form (matches that pattern), specifically the `(ptr)`, but `(ptr)` is not `*(ptr)` and that just doesn't matter unless some other rule makes it matter.